# Incorporating Guice and AOP

Tags: java, aop, guice

I'm building a package that is trying to intercept a function's return value based on a flag. My design involves some AOP. The idea is that a class `FirstIntercept` intercepts a call `firstCall` and stores parameters in a `Parameters` object. Then later, a second class `SecondIntercept` intercepts another call `secondCall` and does some logic based on what is populated in `Parameters`:

```
// pseudoish code 
public class FirstIntercept {
   private Parameters param;

   @AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(* ...firstCall(..))", returning = "payload")
   public void loadParam(Joinpoint joinPoint, Object payload) {
      // logic handling payload returned from firstCall()
      // logic provides a Boolean flag
      this.param = new Parameters(flag);
   }
}



public class Parameters {
   @Getter
   private Boolean flag;

   public Parameters(Boolean flag) {
      this.flag = flag;
   }
}



public class SecondIntercept {
   private static Parameters params;
   
   @Around("execution(* ...secondCall(..))")
   public void handleSecondCallIntercept(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) {
      // want to do logic here based on what params contains
   }
}
```

What I want to achieve is that the `Parameters` object is loaded once and for all when `FirstIntercept.loadParam` is invoked through AOP. I'm not too sure how I can go about with this persistence. I looked online and Google guice seems to be promising. I believe a first step would to use dependency injection on the `Parameters`, but I'm really not sure. Can someone help point me in the right direction?

---

edit:

So I tried this setup:

```
public class FirstIntercept implements MethodInterceptor {
   public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
      System.out.println("invoked!");
      return invocation.proceed();
   }

   @AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(* ...firstCall(..))", returning = "payload")
   public void loadParam(Joinpoint joinPoint, Object payload) {
      // do stuff
   }

   public String firstCall() {
      return "hello";
   }
}

public class InterceptionModule extends AbstractModule {
   protected void configure() {
      FirstIntercept first = new FirstIntercept();
      bindInterceptor(Matchers.any(), Matchers.annotatedWith(AfterReturning.class), first);
   }
}

public class FirstIterceptTest {
   @Test
   public void dummy() {
      Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new InterceptionModule());
      FirstIntercept intercept = injector.getInstance(FirstIntercept.class);

      intercept.firstCall();
   }
}
```

When I do `.firstCall()`, I can see the `@AfterReturning` running but the invoke is not being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you expand upon the documentation for AOP https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AOP you should get something close to:

```java
public class FirstInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {

  @Inject Parameters parameters;  // Injected with singleton Parameter

  public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
    Object result = invocation.proceed();
    // your logic based on result to set parameters.setFlag()
    return result;
  }
}
```

Then the second:

```java
public class SecondInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {

  @Inject Parameters parameters;  // Injected with singleton Parameter

  public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
    boolean flag = parameters.getFlag();
    // your logic here
    return invocation.proceed(); // maybe maybe not?
  }
}
```

Your parameters is the key, **you'll need to ensure it's thread safe**, which is another topic.  But to inject these you need:

```java
public class InterceptionModule extends AbstractModule {
  protected void configure() {
    // Ensure there is only ever one Parameter injected
    bind(Parameter.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);

    // Now inject and bind the first interceptor
    FirstInterceptor firstInterceptor = new FirstInterceptor();
    requestInjection(firstInterceptor );
    bindInterceptor(Matchers.any(), Matchers.annotatedWith(AfterReturning.class),
        firstInterceptor);

    // Now inject and bind the second interceptor
    SecondInterceptor SecondInterceptor = new SecondInterceptor ();
    requestInjection(firstInterceptor);
    bindInterceptor(Matchers.any(), Matchers.annotatedWith(AfterReturning.class),
        SecondInterceptor);
  }
}
```

**Edit**
Look at what you're doing.

1. You're telling Guice to wrap a method with @AfterReturn with the FirstInterceptor
2. Then you're calling interceptor.firstCall()

First call does not have @AfterReturn annotation, so why would it be matched against that configuration?

I'm guessing if you called:

```java
intercept.loadParam();
```

you would see the invoke method.  Also, this is great for a test, but in real life you want to have a Service level class have the @AfterReturn which is then Injected into another Api/Job/Etc that will call LoadParam.

**edit**
Oh no. Take a look at this line

```java
bindInterceptor(Matchers.any(),  // a class with this matcher
   Matchers.annotatedWith(AfterReturning.class),  // a method with this 
        firstInterceptor);
```

This means that the injector only fires on the loadParams. You need to annotate the method of the class youw ish to cause the interception with @AfterReturning. And you want the loadParams to be the invoke method.

Comment: I added the `invoke` method to the `FirstInterceptor`, but it isn't being invoked even when the `@AfterReturning` annotated method is. I made sure to instantiate `Guice.createInjector(new InterceptionModule())` and using `injector.getInstance(FirstInterceptor.class)`

Comment: Read the rules on AOP, can't be private, final, etc.  Also, I don't know where you are using injector.getInstance().  I'd need to see more/all of the code in order to provide better details.

Comment: you're calling a method not annotated with `@AfterReturning`.  If you want the Interceptor to intercept ALL the class methods, just switch matcher around and put the annotation on the class.  But make sure you add the Service class, don't ever wrap intercepter classes with the same interceptor.

Comment: Oh, I thought that anytime a method annotated with `@AfterReturning`, the `invoke` would be called. I'm confused: I would never directly call `intercept.loadParam()` since `loadParam()` would only be triggered when `firstCall()` is called.

Comment: You are correct. Any method annotated with @afterretuening will invoke. Bit you didn't call loadParam. You called firstcall. FirstCall is not annotated. LoadParam is. So why would firstParam trigger it? You need to move the annotation to the firstcall method.